# Update unique values into Postgres Array

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation where I update a `Postgres` table column which is of type `bigint[]`. This array should have unique numbers inside it whenever an `update` query is fired.

The query is as given below

```
UPDATE book_shelf 
SET book_id = book_id || array[CAST(:bookID AS BIGINT)], updated_at = now() 
WHERE user_id = :userID AND shelf_name = :shelfName
```

When the above query is fired, it simply adds the number into the array which I don't want to happen. It should hold only unique values. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if it exists in the array before adding it:

```
UPDATE book_shelf 
SET book_id = CASE WHEN CAST(:bookID AS BIGINT) = ANY(book_id) THEN book_id ELSE ARRAY_APPEND(book_id, CAST(:bookID AS BIGINT)) END, updated_at = now() 
WHERE user_id = :userID AND shelf_name = :shelfName
```

Of course if `updated_at` should only be set if `book_id` is actually updated, then put the check in the WHERE clause so it's not updated unnecessarily:

```
UPDATE book_shelf 
SET book_id = ARRAY_APPEND(book_id, CAST(:bookID AS BIGINT)), updated_at = now() 
WHERE user_id = :userID
AND shelf_name = :shelfName
AND NOT CAST(:bookID AS BIGINT) = ANY(book_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm